# How could you use imshow to show a greyscale image from a row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have this fashion-mnist dataset in which each label is binary (representing two different clothes items) and the feature labels are called pixel1, pixel2, pixel3 etc. The features values are the number of pixels at that feature. The dataset has been imported and converted to a data frame with pandas.

What I'm trying to do here is to take one row and use imshow to display the clothes item as a greyscale image. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
data_train=pd.read_csv("../input/fashion-mnist_train.csv")
data_test=pd.read_csv("../input/fashion-mnist_test.csv")
print ("train size: ",data_train.size, "test data size: ",data_test.size)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
for i in range(0,5):
    sample=np.reshape(data_test[data_test.columns[1:]].iloc[i].values/255,(28,28))
    plt.figure()
    plt.title("Labeled class : {}".format(data_test["label"].iloc[i]))
    plt.imshow(sample, 'gray')
```